# Does Joda-Time have a method called isToday

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to check if a given timestamp is today. I am using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Is there a method or a simple way to check this? What Joda-Time class is better suited for this? [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html)? [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)?

Answer (score 32):

The date can be compared by single statement so why you need a special function.

**when `dateTime`is an object of `DateTime()`**

```
if((dateTime.toLocalDate()).equals(new LocalDate()))
```

**when `date` is an object of `java.util.date`**

```
 if((new DateTime(date).toLocalDate()).equals(new LocalDate()))
```

***What Joda-time class is better suited for this? LocalDate? DateTime?***

The understanding that you need to know what is LocalDate and DateTime.

> `LocalDate()` is an immutable datetime class representing a date without a
>   time zone. So is not having a time part.
>
> `DateTime()` is the standard implementation of an unmodifiable datetime
>   class.  Its having all the attributes of the Date, which includes
>   `date`, `time` and `timezone`.

So if you need to compare both the date and time better go with `datetime`, if you just need to check the date you must use `localDate` because the datetime will produce a `false` if an `.equal` operator is used, unless the time including the seconds part are same for both the objects.

Comment: Why do you create a new DateTime, would it not suffice with a LocalDate? if((dateTime.toLocalDate()).equals(new LocalDate()))

Comment: I could only get this approach to work by using `.isEqual()` instead of `.equals()` for version 2.0.

Comment: toLocalDate makes no sense for readability though. Shouldn't this be toDateWithoutTime or something?

Answer (score 24):

Here are some simple methods to check if a DateTime is today, tomorrow or yesterday:

```
public boolean isToday(DateTime time) {
   return LocalDate.now().compareTo(new LocalDate(time)) == 0;
}

public boolean isTomorrow(DateTime time) {
   return LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).compareTo(new LocalDate(time)) == 0;
}

public boolean isYesterday(DateTime time) {
   return LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).compareTo(new LocalDate(time)) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is to create an interval covering the whole day in question, and then check if the various timestamps are contained in this interval.

Constructing the initial interval could look like:

```
  Interval today = new Interval(DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay(), Days.ONE);
```

Then the timestamps could be checked like so:

```
  today.contains(DateTime.now());                  // True
  today.contains(DateTime.now().minusDays(1));     // False
  today.contains(DateTime.now().plusDays(1));      // False
  today.contains(someOtherTimeStamp.toDateTime()); // And so on...
```

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to do this would be:

```
DateTime midnightToday = DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime myDateTime = <whatever>;
if(myDateTime.isAfter(midnightToday)) {
}
```

I think you need Joda 2.5 to do this, but that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I like @JustinMorris's answer. But I found this even better:

```
public static boolean isToday(DateTime time) {
    return LocalDate.now().equals(new LocalDate(time));
}

public static boolean isTomorrow(DateTime time) {
    return LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).equals(new LocalDate(time));
}

public static boolean isYesterday(DateTime time) {
    return LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).equals(new LocalDate(time));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no direct method available by which you can check the Date is Today Date or not.

The simplest approach will be constructing two `DateTime` one with the Timestamp, and another with today Date and then comparing day from `dayOfYear()` and year from `year()` but do remember whether both Date are in `UTC` or in `Local Time Zone`.
A small sample,

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(TimeStamp);
DateTime todayDate = new DateTime();

if(date.dayOfYear().get() == todayDate.dayOfYear().get() && date.year().get() == todayDate.year().get())
{
    System.out.println("Date is today date");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Joda time actually have a method for this:

```
DateUtils#isToday(ReadablePartial);
DateUtils#isToday(ReadableInstant);
```

Comment: There's no `DateUtils` in `joda`. There's a `DateTimeUtils` but that doesn't feature a method `isToday`

Comment: My bad, it is in joda time for android

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way I've found:

```
public boolean isToday(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis() ==
            new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
}
```